# gRPC - JsonTranscoding - IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, swagger, grpc

I implemented  `JsonTranscoding`
in my simple `gRPC`
application. I've a `POST` 
api. When I test my `POST`
api using swagger, I could call it; but when I test it using Postman or
`HttpClient` (Acually calling api using code) I get two below exception:

> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

and also:

> SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

*** I have no firewall on my local machine.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my `gRPC` service does not support `HTTP` request and this makes problem. so I cofigured it to support `HTTP1` and `HTTP2`. There is two ways to configure it:

Adding below code in `Program.cs` :

```
 builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
    {
        options.ListenAnyIP(7013, listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
            listenOptions.UseHttps();
        });
    });
```

or in `appsettings.json` :

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
    }
  }
```